# Shiny Dashboard Inputs inside MenuItems Problems

Tags: shinydashboard, menu-items

I am new to shiny dashboards and I am trying my hand at making a simple dashboard. I am trying to put together a dashboard that will basically go through different clustering algorithms and show how they work.

I have a menu item for the overall branching topic, and then input items within those menus that specify the parameters for the clustering algorithms.

My issue is I cannot get any output on my screen. I cannot render plots of even see the title for the boxes that I placed inside the tabItems. This seems to happen when I place a sub-item inside one of my menu items. I am not sure why.

Attached is my ui.R script and server.R script.

ui.R file:
[image: ui.R file]

server.R file:

[image: server.R file]

Any help with this matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

So, as far as I can see, the problem is due to the fact that you placed the radioButtons within the `menuItem`. If you want to only show the `radioButtons` when the tab `kclustering` is active, you need to wrap `radioButtons` in a `conditionalPanel`. It would look something like that:

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
   dashboardHeader(title = "Bla"),
   dashboardSidebar(
     sidebarMenu(
       id = "tabs",
       menuItem(
         "K-clustering",
         tabName = "kclustering",
         icon = icon("cogs")),
       conditionalPanel(
         "input.tabs == 'kclustering'",
         radioButtons("technique", "Technique Choice", 
                 c("K-Means" = "kmeans",
                   "K-Medians" = "kmedians",
                   "K-Medoids" = "kmedoids"),
                 select = "kmedians")
         ),
       menuItem("DBSCAN", tabName = "dbscan")
     )
 ),
 dashboardBody(
   tabItems(
     tabItem("kclustering",
       fluidRow(
         box(plotOutput("step1"))
       ))
      )
))

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$step1 <- renderPlot({

    hist(rnorm(5000))

  })

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

In this case, it's important to set the id argument of the `sidebarMenu` object to be able to formulate your condition. 
Bottom line is: don't put your `radioButtons`, `sliderInput` and `textInput` inside the `menuItem` objects but in the `sidebarMenu` object itself.

Comment: the problem with this approach is the nice sliding effect of the menuItem is lost.